# Can effectors apply different effect to different objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm now making my very first 2D game using Unity and I wonder how could 2D Area Effectors apply different effect to different objects.
To be specific, I'm now implementing something like magnetic forces. When a negative charge passes the field (aka. the 2D Area Effector), the force applied to it should be exactly the reverse when a positive charge passes the field.
With 2D Area Effector, I could only apply the same (absorbing) force to both negative charge and positive charge. However, that's not what I want. Do any body has a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need two diffrent Area Effectors attached to one GameObject. Each Effector has diffrent colliderMask dependings on `Layer`, which it should affect.